# Selenium testing in docker compose environment

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose

I have 3 docker containers:

1. Web app
2. End to end tests: These are selenium tests for the above web app
3. Selenium: I am using this: https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome

I am spinning up the containers with compose as follows:

```yaml
  web-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    image: web-app
    command: poetry run ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000

  e2e-tests:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: e2etests.dockerfile
    image: e2e-tests
    volumes:
      - ./e2e_tests:/app

  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:91.0
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
```

The `e2etests.dockerfile` simply installs python and the selenium python package. Nothing fancy.

Here’s a very basic selenium test in python:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver_1 = webdriver.Remote("selenium:4444/wd/hub", options=chrome_options)

driver_1.get(‘http://web-app:8000/')

assert 'Api Root' in driver_1.title

driver_1.quit()
```

The above test does not work. It hangs on the web `driver.Remote()` step. It looks like that step is unable to resolve the IP address or dns of the other container. I figured this out by typing `docker inspect container_id | grep IPAddress` to get the IP address of the selenium container.

I then updated that step to use the IP address as follows:

```py
driver_1 = webdriver.Remote("http://ip_address_here:4444/wd/hub", options=chrome_options)
```

The tests now works.

So my question is, how do I spin up the containers from compose in such a way that I can use their host names in the web driver.Remote() step instead of having to manually figure out what the IP address is.

Comment: You don't need to do anything; the DNS resolution should work as-is.  See [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation for more details.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't. If I open up a shell inside the e2e-tests container and ping the selenium container it will work. However the above webdriver.Remote() with the dns name it does not work. It only works when using the ip address as mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one, it should work:

```py
driver_1 = webdriver.Remote("http://selenium:4444/wd/hub", options=chrome_options)
```